# Does MSSQL store filename when we store pdf in blob?

Tags: c#, sql-server, pdf

I have a program where we use to store our documents in PDF format.
At the moment , the program is able to do PDF generation based on user input , with filename automatically generated with transaction ID included.

However I also have an upload feature where user will need to upload a signed(signature) document to chosen transaction ID. This class does not check for the document name upon upload.

My question is , when mssql store the document in blob ( example 0x21349182361293871 ) , does mssql also store the filename in that blob string?

If yes , how do I extract the filename in that blob so upon downloading the file , I can reattach the filename so I can proceed to have my code check if file is PDF or not.

At the moment here's my download code :

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var LMTF2 = new LogToFile();
    string appdb = "someconnstring";
    tempfileName = Path.GetTempFileName();

    string tempfileloc = tempfileName;
    SNe = importID.Text.ToString();
    cdoc2 = cDoc.SelectedValue.ToString();

    using (SqlConnection sqlconnection = new SqlConnection(appdb))
    {
        sqlconnection.Open();
        dLoad = new DataSet();
        string selectQuery = "Select " + cdoc2 + " From StaffTrans Where TransID=" + SNe;

        try
        {
            SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, sqlconnection);
            SqlDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                byte[] fileData = (byte[])reader[0];
                // Write/Export File content into new text file
                File.WriteAllBytes(tempfileloc, fileData);

            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot locate file! File doesn't exist or wrong transaction ID. Exception error : " + ex.Message);
            LMTF2.LogMessageToFile("Cannot locate file! File doesn't exist or wrong transaction ID " + ex.Message);
        }

        try
        {
            //Open downloaded file
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(tempfileloc);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot Open Downloaded File. File could be corrupted. : " + ex.Message);
            LMTF2.LogMessageToFile("Cannot locate file! File doesn't exist or wrong transaction ID " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried adding

```
string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(tempfileloc);
```

but this gives me nothing.

Comment: `does mssql also store the filename in that blob string?` No.

Comment: no it does not, it just saves the content without knowing what it is

Comment: If you need to store additional data, such as the file's name, extension, inserted date, etc, you need to do so in different columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not,  If you are looking to be able to determine if the file is a pdf.  I would add that validation logic in upon Upload of file.  Alter the upload to determine the file extension prior to allowing it to upload.  If it isn't the correct format, Send a message box, and don't allow them to save this back incorrectly

Comment: Hi , i do have validation and file name saved upon Upload. File name is on different column in my DB. just curious if blob saves Filename as well.

This is due to i have 2 document or 3 document blob column and i only save the first document name.

Comment: Thanks. Then i guess i will change my code to retrieve original file name based on Document 1 for all of my document since its the same document , just different signatures within the document.

Comment: @MohdNasrulIwanFajaruddin Blobs can store **any** binary data, including things other than files. Thus, no file name. However, the fact that the binary data in question is supposed to be not only a PDF, but a **signed** PDF, may mean the original file name is present as part of the metadata in the signature. But I wouldn't expect to be able to read that in your code. And speaking of "binary data", it's also grossly incorrect to refer to it as "blob string". It's more of a byte array.